# How to get the naturalSize of Vuetify v-img?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

So I need to get the sizes of an image shown in my page using Vuetify v-img.
I tried to get the size with `naturalHeight` and `naturalWidth` by doing so:

```
//markup
<v-img ref="imageShow" @load="getSizes" src"/images/background.jpg"></v-img>

//method
getSizes(){
   console.log(this.$refs.imageShow.naturalHeigth)
}
```

but it didn't show me the size, it returns undefined.

Comment: v-img is not the same as html5 img. its a vue component that likely contains the img tag. it probably doesn't have those variables defined in the v-img component.

Comment: it looks like naturalWidth is defined in the component's data object but height is not. It's pull dynamically in functions but not returned to anything outside of the function scope. Perhaps if you need it then it would be better to pull it separately without the use of the v-img component at all. https://stackoverflow.com/a/626505/8551436

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vuetify's `v-img` component renders `<div>` HTML elements instead of `<img>` and `naturalHeight` and `naturalWidth` work only on `<img>` HTML elements. I checked [Vuetify's documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/images/) for `v-img` and it doesn't seem to have a property to configure the html tag.

[HTMLImageElement.naturalHeight reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalHeight)

Answer (score 3):

VImg renders on a [VResponsive](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/ad37f7e11c54cae6f4a6d1de8dbff998b7dc2b57/packages/vuetify/src/components/VImg/VImg.ts#L257), and puts the image in a div as [backgroundimage](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/ad37f7e11c54cae6f4a6d1de8dbff998b7dc2b57/packages/vuetify/src/components/VImg/VImg.ts#L118).

#### It is not a HTMLImageElement.

But maybe you can abuse an integrated [onLoad](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/ad37f7e11c54cae6f4a6d1de8dbff998b7dc2b57/packages/vuetify/src/components/VImg/VImg.ts#L198) event and access its [vm.image](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/ad37f7e11c54cae6f4a6d1de8dbff998b7dc2b57/packages/vuetify/src/components/VImg/VImg.ts#L186), which is a HTMLImageElement | null.

```
getSizes(){
   // unless loading error
   const {naturalHeight, naturalWidth} = this.$refs.imageShow.image;
   console.log(naturalHeight, naturalWidth);
}
```

Or you can extend this component for your needs:

```js
let vuetifyOptions;
Vuetify.install({
  use(_, options){
     vuetifyOptions: {...options}
  }
})

const VImg = vuetifyOptions.components.VImg;


export default {
  extends: VImg,
  data(){
    return {
      naturalHeight: null,
      naturalWidth: null
    }
  }
  onLoad(){
    this.naturalHeight = this.image.naturalHeight
    this.naturalWidth = this.image.naturalWidth
    this.$emit('naturals', this.image)
    this.$emit('load', this.src)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look under the hood, you find Vuetify uses the background image of a `DIV` element, and not an `IMG` element.  If you then take apart the engine, you find the natural width and aspect ratio stashed in the Vue component.

I needed to extract this in a pinch, so I did the following.  I'm not recommending this non-API hack, but "it is what it is".

I was not able to access the Component from my code, so needed to grab the dimensions from the element proper.

```js
const naturalWidth = divElement.__vue__.naturalWidth
const naturalHeight = naturalWidth / divElement.__vue__.computedAspectRatio
```

You can also check your element is a `v-img`, and get the html image element from the component

```js
if (divElement.classList.contains('v-image')) {
  const img = divElement.__vue__?.image as HTMLImageElement
  if (img?.complete) {
    process(img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight)
  }
}
```

Finally, make sure you wait for the `loaded` event.